# What does "style="?textTitle" mean and how does it work?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, menu

I have an xml file on my PC. Something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_text"
    style="?textTitle"/>
```

In attrs.xml is defined:

```
<attr name="textTitle" format="reference" />
```

In an style.xml file is written:

```
<style name="text_title_bl">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#DDD</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF004488</item>
</style>
```

My question is how does it work, that eclipse knows that "?textTitle" belongs to this style above? Or why is "?textTitle" = "text_title_bl"? It is an example which works with multiple themes.

Thank for your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` means "look this up in the current theme, and use that value". In this case, that value from the theme is then used as the style name.

Your theme has an entry with the key "textTitle" and the value "text_title_bl". If you changed this in your theme, the textview would use a different style.

Comment: Oh yea, thank for your answer. I forgot to look at another xml where the themes are defined: 

<style name="Theme.Blue">
<item name="pageBackground">@style/page_background_bl</item>
<ITEM NAME="textTitle">@style/text_title_bl</ITEM>
<item name="textTitleHidden">@style/text_title_hidden_bl</item>
<item name="textRegular">@style/text_regular_bl</item>
<item name="whiteBackground">@style/white_background_bl</item>
<item name="button">@style/button_bl</item>
<item name="list">@style/list_bl</item>
<item name="listDivider">@style/list_divider_bl</item>
</style>

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I wrote the important row with "item" in capital letters. Now it is almost clear. Last question why do I need this row from attrs.xml?: <attr name="textTitle" format="reference" /> Is it necessary to use the "?"?

Comment: @PeterPanne that line is what makes textTitle a valid attribute. It doesn't have a "?" so I don't know what your second last question is about.